# Find componentInfo name for custom icon

Tags: android

I have been trying to customize ameixa, an open-source icon pack to add some missing icons.

The source I base myself on with can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/xphnx/ameixa).

I do not intend to add new icons (yet), only to re-use existing ones for some applications that are not supported yet.

For that purpose, I have been adding entries to `src/main/res/xml/appfilter.xml`

In order to find the `ComponentInfo`'s name, I have been using openlauncher's "hide apps" feature, which gives me the full package name and activity of apps he can see (for instance, `com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activity.Activity`).

My problem is that some of the apps I use don't mention an activity name, but only the app (for instance, `com.myapp.app/`). I have tried using both this, as well as some obvious activity names (`com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.(App/acitivity.MainActivity...`), but none of those worked.

By trying to compare with some other apps that already are shown without a right-hand definition in the already-existing source code, I don't see an obvious pattern to try.

Do any of you know how I can figure out the exact `ComponentInfo` name I need to enter to a given app icon ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution, maybe not the best but it works.

I have been building locally my own version of openlauncher (any other launcher should do), and checked in the code where the list of app is built.

By putting a breakpoint there and debugging my application, I could access the properties "package name" and "activity name" which are enough as a name for the `ComponentInfo` definition.

Maybe there is a faster/easier way to achieve that, but that's what ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to download Nova Launcher. Long press on an icon to bring up a menu, and then press "Edit". This will show the icon along with the ComponentInfo below it. You can long press on this to copy the text.